# create dependent filter in view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am using D7, I want to create a dependent filter in view .
Now I use taxonomy to create three vocabulary : Device, Unit Type, Format .

Device has two value PC and mobile , unit type values belongs to PC and mobile , Format values belong to Unit type .
I want it to show like : choose PC, then the value for Unit type only show the list belong to PC, and when choose 'PC type one', then the value for Format only show the list belong to Unit type.

> [image]

I try to use the module dependent filter in view , but it can't create the relations between the three list. anyone can give any suggestion and guidance will be very thanks .

Comment: you can do it with https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select or https://drupal.org/project/shs

Comment: @Bala why not to answer, then?